# How to use stored procedure to calculate DateTime difference in hours?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have two tables, TicketReport and TimeTracker.

**TicketReport Columns**:

Ticket_Number

Report_DT (DateTime ticket was reported)

Response_Time (Hourly value. How long it took for this ticket to be responded to. This is where I need the place the hours. DateTime Reported minus DateTime started)

**TimeTracker Column**:

Ticket_Number

Time_Start( DateTime that work started on this ticket)

Right now, for every row in my TicketReport table, the Response_Time column contains either Null or just a test value of 1(hour).

*I need to calculate how many hours it took for a ticket to be responded to (ReportDT - Time_Start), and then insert that hourly value into the Report_DT column for each row in the TicketReport table.

I did some research and found DATEDIFF, but I think this only returns days, and even if it did return hours, im not sure how to use it.

How could I accomplish this in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the `response_time` column with the number of hours you can use a simple update query (which you could wrap in a stored proc if you need.

The query could look like this:

```
-- uncomment the next line to create a sp...
-- create proc update_response_time as 
update tr
set response_time = datediff(hour, report_dt, time_start)
from TicketReport tr
join TimeTracker tt on tr.Ticket_Number = tt.Ticket_Number
```

If you want to run it without updating (to see what the values would be) you can run it as a select query:

```
select *, datediff(hour, report_dt, time_start) as diff_in_hours
from TicketReport tr
join TimeTracker tt on tr.Ticket_Number = tt.Ticket_Number
```

Be aware that these queries assume that there are just one matching row in the TimeTracker table for each ticket. If there can be multiple rows you would need another solution. Also know that the hour value doesn't take minutes into account at all so if `report_dt` is at `12:00` and `time_start` is at `12:30` it would be reported as `0 hours`, so maybe a finer granularity than hours would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF` function

Syntax

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

pass datepart `hh` to get hours